# Work script in two different stores

Tags: stores, script

I was running now a script.
The script works on the currentStore-> 0

But now, the Store 1 is a bit different, and it need to run the script too.

How i can call both stores in the same script?

I show the code that i do.

```
require_once( __DIR__ . '/../app/Mage.php');

umask( 0 );

$store_id = 0;
$store_id_dutch = 1;
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore( $store_id );


// Check simple products in first place
$simple_products = $collection = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter( 'type_id', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE )
        ->getAllIds();


foreach ( $simple_products as $product_id )
{
// Script runs here, the same for both
}
```

Now i run it only in `$store_id` , but i want it too on `$store_id_dutch`

Any idea?

Comment: `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore( $store_id_dutch);` instead of `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore( $store_id );` maybe

Comment: I know, but i dont want to run the script 2 times, i want to make the changes on products in both stores at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$storeIds = array(0, 1);
foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore( $storeId );
    // Check simple products in first place
    $simple_products = $collection = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter( 'type_id', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE )
        ->getAllIds();


    foreach ( $simple_products as $product_id )
    {
    // Script runs here, the same for both
    }
}
```

Comment: In any case, through the loop twice repeating all products twice, right?
Is there another way?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing with the products after that. There might be a better way.

Comment: I was doing this:
In case that the product price is lower than X or Qty is lower or equal to 0, change the Status.
In other case, change the status too.

Any better task for this?